# how to convert a query into a parametric one in C++ Builder 10.2

Tags: c++, sql, parameters

I have "normal" string query

```
String sqlquery = Format("select * from events where location = %d",ARRAYOFCONST(parameter_value));
```

how to convert this query into a parametric one in C++ Builder 10.2
(i use postgres database)

Comment: Which component(s) exactly are you using to access the database? Different components may have different syntaxes for parameterized queries

Comment: because I use postgres server I use external component: TPSQLQuery and TPSQLDatabase (PostgresDAC).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [`TPSQLQuery.SQL`](https://www.microolap.com/products/connectivity/postgresdac/help/tpsqlquery_properties_sql.htm) property documentation:

> The SQL statement in the `SQL` property may contain replaceable parameters, following standard SQL-92 syntax conventions. Parameters are created and stored in the [`Params`](https://www.microolap.com/products/connectivity/postgresdac/help/tpsqlquery_properties_params.htm) property.

For example:

```cpp
PSQLQuery1->ParamCheck = true; // true by default
PSQLQuery1->SQL->Text = "select * from events where location = :Location";
PSQLQuery1->Params->Items[0]->AsInteger =  parameter_value;
// alternatively:
// PSQLQuery1->ParamByName("Location")->AsInteger = parameter_value;
PSQLQuery1->Open();
...
```

Have a look at the [`TPSQLQuery.Params`](https://www.microolap.com/products/connectivity/postgresdac/help/tpsqlquery_properties_params.htm) documentation for more details.